# What is a common pattern for scheduled event handling in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

In my application I need to add scheduled event checking and handling. When some business logic happened I need to create a posponed trigger, which should fire some actions through a particular time gap. For example:

If user posted photo, he should be notified if there is no likes under it within three days.

I feel that it should be a common pattern for such activities, relied on Spring framework features.

Answer (score 2):

In your main config you need some like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class HelloWorldConfig { ..}
```

Then in you bean where you want to schedule something :

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
 public void reload()  { ..}
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Make sure you include the @EnableScheduling or equivalent if you're using XML config.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the linked content in your answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer in view of the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class DemoExpirationEvent implements Runnable {

    @Resource(name = "demoPhotoService")
    private DemoExpirationService demoExpirationService;

    @Resource(name = "demoExpirationTaskScheduler")
    private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    private Long id;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        demoExpirationService.expiration(id);     
    }

    public void schedule(Long id, Date dateToExpire){
        this.id = id;
        taskScheduler.schedule(this, dateToExpire);
    }
}

@Service("demoPhotoService")
public class DemoPhotoServiceImpl implements DemoExpirationService, DemoPhotoService {

    @Override
    public void expiration(Long id) {
        DemoPhoto photo = getPhoto(id); 
        photo.setExpirationDate(null);
        savePhoto(photo);
        notifyAuthorOfPhoto(id); 
    }

    @Override
    public void getPhoto(long id){
         //some implementation
    }

    @Override
    public void savePhoto(DemoPhoto photo){
         //some implementation
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyAuthorOfPhoto(long id){
         //some implementation
    }
}


public class DemoAddedPhotoActivity {

    @Resource(name = "demoExpirationEvent")
    private DemoExpirationEvent demoExpirationEvent;

    @Resource(name = "demoPhotoService")
    private DemoPhotoService demoPhotoService;

    public void execute(long id) throws Exception {
        DemoPhoto photo = demoPhotoService.getPhoto(id);
        Date expirationDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000000000L);

        photo.setExpirationDate(expirationDate);
        demoPhotoService.savePhoto(photo);
        demoExpirationEvent.schedule(id,  expirationDate);
    }
}
```

- register task scheduler in your applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">

<task:scheduler id="demoExpirationTaskScheduler" pool-size="3"/>
```

- And rest of beans too and call activity on adding photo (it can be controller method with execute like method